# How to get colored text in Android without using SpannableStringBuilder?

Tags: java, android, c++, android-ndk, spannablestring

I'm trying to make a fast Android code editor. Currently, this is the approach I'm taking:

- Tokenize the source code
- Assign different colors to spans of text, based on the type of the tokens
- Call `SpannableStringBuilder.setSpan(new ForegroundColorSpan(color))` for each of those colors

As you can imagine, for large files (1000 lines+) I'm attaching tens of thousands of spans. I noticed that when I edit large files, the app freezes for 2+ seconds when I try to delete a single character. I tracked it down to `SpannableStringBuilder.replace` doing a lot of work behind-the-scenes: https://github.com/aosp-mirror/platform_frameworks_base/blob/e72b6f0d3113c84df6d9113609942ef5d9b4e34e/core/java/android/text/SpannableStringBuilder.java

This method calls `change` and `restoreInvariants`, both of which have loops like this:

```
for (int i = 1; i < mSpanCount; i++) {
    ...
}
```

`mSpanCount` is typically around 20000 for 1000-line files, so these loops are extremely costly.

Is there a way to get colored text in Android without use of `SpannableStringBuilder`? I'm willing to deal with lower-level solutions that involve the C++ side of Android, or require me to stitch some things together.

Comment: Use `WebView` and a JS-based rich editor. Or use one `EditText` per line, rather than one for all lines (as I assume that you're doing), so that each individual `Spannable` has relatively few spans. Or create your own text-editing widget from scratch that uses low-level `Canvas` operations and some other system for managing the formatting. With an `EditText` (or anything inheriting from `TextView`), you're pretty much stuck with the `Spannable` system for inline formatting.

Comment: @CommonsWare Your second solution (breaking up the `EditText`) sounds interesting. Any idea how I might be able to let users highlight multiple lines of text with that solution?

Comment: Another theoretical possibility would be to create another `Spannable`+`Editable` implementation that would be used as a `SpannableStringBuilder` replacement, if you think that you can come up with an optimized version. `SpannableStringBuilder` most likely is naive and conservative. Whether there is a smarter implementation that is possible, I can't say. "Any idea how I might be able to let users highlight multiple lines of text with that solution?" -- via keyboard, you might be able to fake it, but via touchscreen or mouse, that is going to be tricky at best.

Comment: if you have 1000+ lines break them up and use `RecyclerView` / `ListView` / whatever adapter based view

Comment: @pskink That will prevent the user from being able to highlight multiple lines.